# Wordpress Img src

Tags: html, wordpress

Wordpress is not recognizing my img src, even tho i used php bloginfo! 
Here's my code
Thanks in advance !

```
<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?> images/Subtração 2.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" class="social__instagram">
        </a>
```

I have also tried

```
src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample.jpg"
```

but didn't work

Comment: What is showing up in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the examples you try are using completely different locations.

Where are your images located?

If they're at the root, why are you using an absolute url for the src?

Why can't you just use `<img src="/images/Subtração 2.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" class="social__instagram">` ?

If your images are in an images folder in your theme, then you need to use `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Subtração 2.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" class="social__instagram">`.

PS. You have whitespaces in your image filenames. You need to fix these.

Comment: My images are located in a folder called "images" inside my theme folder, i tried to use the simple src link without the php echo but didn't work.

Comment: Okay, does the second example I've given work? Like I said in my comment in your question, you need to look in the console to see if any obvious reasons why are listed.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem where my files are located ? i have the folder "img" located outside my custom theme folder, but i also have the folder "images" inside the folder of my custom theme, inside my wp-content folder

Comment: What does your console say..?

Comment: Sometimes says 404 not found, sometimes nothing at all

Comment: Rename the file so there's no space in it (I think this is why), also add a `height` and `width` attribute to the `img` element, as it seems using an SVG as an img src requires these.

Comment: WAIT , figured it out , i was putting the images in the wrong directory ! thanks a lot the second code worked !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add "echo"

```
<img  src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/Subtração 2.svg" alt="instagram" title="instagram" class="social__instagram">
```

If you are using child theme then you need to use this below path

```
src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sample.jpg"
```

Hope it will works
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use get_home_url() to get domain and add string for your url image. But images folder must created in root folder.

```
src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/sample.jpg"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code `<?php ?>` tag should be close in img tag and use concatenate (.) within your URL It will get the correct path.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url').'/images/Subtração 2.svg;?>" alt="instagram" title="instagram" class="social__instagram">
        </a>
```